# Reenable Turbo Core MSI GX70

Tags: windows-7, cpu, amd-radeon, overclocking

I was tinkering with overdrive on my MSI GX70 with windows 7. I tried fiddling with CPU cycles and it asked me do you want to disable the TurboCore, which it did. However, now I can't seem to turn it back on. I tried uninstalling and deleting the directories and restarted and then reinstalled. I also tried to search for any option in the BIOS but to no avail. How can I fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled powernow in the BIOS and then clicked the green button, so that it gets surrounded by a red circle. The Turbo Core got switched back on.